# Why does TestNG initialize all test classes at startup

Tags: java, testng

I have a very simple test suite similar to the following:

```java
public abstract class AbstractTestClass {
    protected AbstractTestClass() {
        System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}

@Test(groups = { "test1_test_group" })
public final class Test1 extends AbstractTestClass { ... }

@Test(groups = { "test2_test_group" })
public final class Test2 extends AbstractTestClass { ... }
```

```xml
<!-- testng.xml -->
<suite name="SimpleTestSuite">
    <test name="DummyTest">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="test1_test_group" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <packages>
            <package name="my.test.package.*" />
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I'm not sure if it is by design but why does TestNG creates an instance of all classes in the given package when the only test group I want to execute is test1_test_group i.e. the output of the above test run is as follows:

```
Test1
Test2
```

I've tried to remove the complete <packages> tag replacing it with <classes> tags listing individual classes but it's the same behavior. The only defect reported which comes close to this scenario (although kind of rejected) is https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1075

Comment: I am working with version 6.9.10 just in case

Comment: I closed the issue because it is how testng is working for years. If you really want an explanation, only @cbeust will be able to provide one ;)

Comment: What do you intend to do? Running selected test case/cases?

Comment: @optimist_creeper yes, if possible without unnecessarily instantiating classes which have nothing to do with the test group being executed

Answer (score 0):

Change your testng xml file. Remove the package, instead use classes as follows:

```
<suite name="SimpleTestSuite">
    <test name="DummyTest">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="test1_test_group" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="your class with fully qualified name where tests are written" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```